# Get Memory Address that is changed by Opcode

Tags: c#, assembly, memory, opcode

Ok, so this has been troubling me for several days, and I've searched everywhere for a solution to no avail. I have a list of memory addresses that are all written to by the same op code "mov [rbx+30],eax" and I am trying to return this list of addresses in C#, but each approach I've taken has not worked. Is this possible to do in C#?

Comment: Is this a question about calling a C/C++ DLL from C#?

Comment: This `mov` is a disassembly of JITed IL or is it a portion of unmanaged code called from C#?

Comment: Well, I know i need to attach a debugger to the process, from there i need to retrieve all memory addresses that are changed by a specific instruction.

Comment: process.exe+167755 - 89 43 30              - mov [rbx+30],eax is the instruction
I'm just trying to retrieve the addresses because i cannot get a pointer that will stay. I just want to be able to consistently get the correct set of addresses without changing offsets to pointers

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is the **underlying** problem?

Comment: the underlying problem is that my pointers are inconsistent, and it is a hassle to constantly update the offset each time the program is restarted. I don't want you guys to think i haven't put forth any effort. I've been reading online for days about assembly, I'm just having trouble getting a grasp on it. Is there no function that can just return all addresses accessed by a specific instruction?

Comment: @mkwhite703 With ASLR, Windows loads your programs to a different address at each start, so of course all addresses will be different (or “inconsistent”) every time you restart your program. You can turn off ASLR if that makes debugging easier for you.

Comment: @mkwhite703 What do you mean “a specific instruction?” Do you mean “all `mov` instructions?” or “this one instruction there, whenever it is executed” or “this one instruction there this one time it was executed?” It is very unclear what you try to achieve and hard to answer your question.

Comment: @fuz No i do not mean all `mov` instructions. i mean that specific instruction i posted. I just want to return the few addresses that it writes to in C#

Comment: Since that depends on the value in `rbx`, you simply can't do that.

Comment: @Jester what if i had a static pointer to rbx?

Comment: rbx is a register. You can't point to it. Do you mean one instance of that instruction or all such instructions in your program?

Comment: If you want that for particular instruction, you can probably put there breakpoint with automated handler, which will keep storing the addresses in `rbx`, but it sounds like lot of effort for something what will probably not help you in the end, it's not clear what kind of inconsistency is bothering you. Maybe check the code ahead of the `mov`, how the `rbx` is set, maybe it will give you better idea what kind of addresses may be used there and why/when. But just with `mov [rbx+30],eax` instruction you can basically overwrite whole physical memory, if you want (by using all possible addresses)

Comment: In general you are probably talking about a variation of the halting problem, and that is unsolvable. In specific, you will have to give us a lot more specifics.

Comment: @NetMage well, the best example i could provide would be, In the program Cheat Engine. In the code list there is an option to "Find out what addresses this code writes to" I'm literally just trying to replicate that